# Rpi not reading data from Sense HAT due to missing frame buffer

Tags: pi-3, gpio, i2c, raspbian-stretch, sense-hat

I'm having trouble getting my RPi 3  to listen to a Sense HAT.

The Sense Hat is getting power and the RPI is aware of the Hat.

`pi@BBLPi1:~ $ ls /dev/i2c*
/dev/i2c-1
pi@BBLPi1:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1c -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- 46 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 5c -- -- 5f 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 6a -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --`

However, there's no frame buffer.

`pi@BBLPi1:~ $ cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/name
BCM2708 FB`

I was expecting the Sense HAT to also be listed here but it's not.

I found a posting on the Rpi Linux repo that seemed promising: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1139#issue-108231030.  However, I'm not compiling or cross-compiling Linux.  Having to customize Linux just to get the HAT working seems like overkill.

I've tried a few things just to remove as many variables from the situation.  But it turns out that this issue arises both when using a Rpi 3 model B and B+.  It also happens when the device is running  NOOBS or Raspian lite.  Ultimately, both those OS's are using some Debian Stretch. So maybe it's just a problem with Stretch? I'm not sure.

I'm baffled that none of the Sense HAT tutorials out there mentioned this missing buffer issue.

If anyone has any suggestions about how to get this missing frame buffer to appear, please let me know.

Comment: Do you just have 1 framebuffer? No ./dev/fb1 ? That's where I would expect the sensehat.

Comment: There is no `/dev/fb1`.  Only `dev/fb0`.

Comment: Is the sense-hat package installed? Use e.g. 'apt-cache policy sense-hat'

Comment: Yep.  It's installed.  It was the sense-hat library that started my investigation into the frame buffer issue.   It throws an `OSError: Cannot detect RPi-Sense FB device` when I attempt to use it.

Comment: It should not be necessary, but you could try to add the line 'dtoverlay=rpi-sense' to /boot/config.txt

Comment: When I add that setting, the RPi's screen starts flickering once it gets about halfway into the boot process.

Comment: Ok, but do you have a second framebuffer after startup (/dev/fb1)?

Comment: With dtoverlay set,  It can't even finish booting.

Comment: Turns out...it was the device. I swapped in a different Sense HAT and everything worked beautifully.